# Why is the verb сниться governed by the object?

Tags: спряжение

> Ты мне снишься каждую ночь.

I get that ты is the subject, but to my English-speaking mind, the person dreaming is the one performing the action, and so the person dreamt about should be the object.

What is a good way to explain this usage to an English-speaking person?

The closest I can get is: "You came to me in a dream". In this case, "dream" ceases to be a verb so the translation is not exactly verbatim.

Comment: This is a very good question, but translations to English and other languages are off-topic on this site. I've amended the question a little bit so that it stays on-topic, hope that's OK.

Comment: @Quassnoi thanks very much for the edit. The question now more aptly captures what I meant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, sometimes, subjects and objects may get swapped in translation, just like in the phrases "у меня есть X"/"I have X", or "мне нужен X"/"I need X". This is just something you need to remember — it's a quirk of this verb. Unfortunately, I don't think there's a more reasonable explanation — that's just how it is. In this case, I cannot think of any translation that would be more literal than "you come to me in a dream every night".

Сни́ться (imperfective) / присни́ться (perfective) means "to come in a dream", it can have an indirect object that states who was having that dream, and this indirect object needs to be in dative case (so: "A+Nom сни́ться B+Dat" means that A came to B in a B's dream) and it usually corresponds to the English phrase "to dream about smth" (NOT to "dream *of* smth" — it's not used in a figurative meaning of "to want smth really bad").

- Мне снилась мама. - I was dreaming about mom. (verbatim: Mom was coming to me in a dream.)
- Мне сегодня приснилась мама. - I dreamed about mom today. (verbatim: Today, mom came to me in a dream.)
- Я помню, мы это обсуждали. Мне же это не приснилось? - I remember we  discussed this. It wasn't a dream[, right?]

Comment: Good point that this just happens (fortunately or unfortunately :-) ). Сниться - being reflexive verb is an interesting fact - but not so much relevant here. This 'inversion' of subject and object also happens in other language pairs. The most famous example is probably _Le livre me plait_ (in French) translates to _I like the book_ (in English). Literally The book brings me pleasure, which just means I like the book.

Answer (score 6):

In Russian, when we have the reflexive suffix `ся,` which means, in general, that the action is directed towards the speaker, it's like an inverstion of the subject and the object.
Example:

`мыть` - to wash 
`мыться` - to take a shower, it's like `to wash myself`

Of course, language is irregular and some verbs only exist in the reflexive form, like "сниться."

So `сниться` is best translated as `to be in someone's dream`.

Consequently, the closest verbatium translation would be `You are (or exist) in my dreams every night`, because you can't reverse the subject and the object in English like that.

Interesting fact: `-ся` came from `себя`, which literally translates to `myself.`

(I'm not good in english, please sorry for missused tenses and verb forms — Russian is my native language.)

Comment: +1 Just mention that the topic discussed is called возвратные глаголы

Comment: Nice to learn that `-ся` came from `себя`

Answer (score 0):

How about "I saw you in a dream" vs "You appeared in my dream"?

Thus, you can think of **сниться** as of 'to appear in a dream', "явиться во сне".